# How to generate values inside a time period in a python dataframe?

Tags: pandas, interpolation, nested-loops

I have some data inside a specific period range (period 0, 1, 2...) and I would like to create values that are inside the periods that will get the difference of the values and divide for the total of periods that will be set;

For instance:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'metric': '3f00d0b5', 'time':52.66, 'time_order': 0, 'variable': 'var1', 'value': 0.035},
        {'metric': '3f00d0b5', 'time':422.4, 'time_order': 1, 'variable': 'var1', 'value': 0.512},
        {'metric': '3f00d0b5', 'time':620.1, 'time_order': 2, 'variable': 'var1', 'value': 0.0},
        
        {'metric': '3f00d0b5', 'time':52.66, 'time_order': 0, 'variable': 'var2', 'value': 0.007},
        {'metric': '3f00d0b5', 'time':422.4, 'time_order': 1, 'variable': 'var2', 'value': 0.012},
        {'metric': '3f00d0b5', 'time':620.1, 'time_order': 2, 'variable': 'var2', 'value': 0.214},
            
        {'metric': '83e7fdd1', 'time':25.42, 'time_order': 0, 'variable': 'var1', 'value': 0.0},
        {'metric': '83e7fdd1', 'time':322.45, 'time_order': 1, 'variable': 'var1', 'value': 0.241},
        {'metric': '83e7fdd1', 'time':678.12, 'time_order': 2, 'variable': 'var1', 'value': 0.005},
        
        {'metric': '83e7fdd1', 'time':25.42, 'time_order': 0, 'variable': 'var2', 'value': 0.02},
        {'metric': '83e7fdd1', 'time':322.45, 'time_order': 1, 'variable': 'var2', 'value': 0.007},
        {'metric': '83e7fdd1', 'time':678.12, 'time_order': 2, 'variable': 'var2', 'value': 0.0}
]
    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Based on the data above the final result I'm looking for is:

```
{'metric': '3f00d0b5',  'time':52.66, 'time_order': 0, 'variable': 'var1', 'value': 0.035},
{'metric': '3f00d0b5',  'time':52.66, 'time_order': 0.1, 'variable': 'var1', 'value': 0.083},
...
{'metric': '3f00d0b5',  'time':52.66, 'time_order': 0.9, 'variable': 'var1', 'value': 0.4643},
{'metric': '3f00d0b5',  'time':422.4, 'time_order': 1, 'variable': 'var1', 'value': 0.512},
```

There are a straightforward way to implement this in a pythonic way?

Thank you in advance,
Leonardo

Comment: Periods are always the same for each (metric, variable)?

Comment: Yes; Each metric will always have the same variables and the same periods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and a custom function to augment the data:

```
def data_augment(df):
    new_index = np.arange(df['time_order'].min(), df['time_order'].max()+0.1, 0.1)
    return (df.set_index('time_order')['value']
              .reindex(new_index).interpolate())
    
out = (df.groupby(['metric', 'variable']).apply(data_augment)
         .stack().rename('value').reset_index()[df.columns])
```

Output:

```
>>> out
      metric  time_order variable   value
0   3f00d0b5         0.0     var1  0.0350
1   3f00d0b5         0.1     var1  0.0827
2   3f00d0b5         0.2     var1  0.1304
3   3f00d0b5         0.3     var1  0.1781
4   3f00d0b5         0.4     var1  0.2258
..       ...         ...      ...     ...
79  83e7fdd1         1.6     var2  0.0028
80  83e7fdd1         1.7     var2  0.0021
81  83e7fdd1         1.8     var2  0.0014
82  83e7fdd1         1.9     var2  0.0007
83  83e7fdd1         2.0     var2  0.0000

[84 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: You can use `out.to_dict('records')` to get the expected output.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, man! Be sure that I will accept it as the answer as it is exactly what I was looking for... but I found some limitations to incorporating this in my code as I didn't set all the variables here; I have added a new column called 'TIME' and that should be shown in the final data... Could you please add the time column? I tried adding the column by myself but unfortunately it raised some errors that I wasn't understanding

Comment: Just to become clearer, the column time_order becomes from dividing the time column by 300; I'm doing it all to try to smooth a Plotly chart that is animated

Comment: I have created a dictionary of each time_order & metric combination with the correspondent time as value and it solved the problem;